How can I calculate the arrival time of a bus on a specific route?
I'm creating an app to track the location of buses in my city. My goal is to show in the app how long it will take for the next bus to arrive at a selected stop.
Each bus follows a specific route, which I have defined through points (coordinates). Of course, the positions of my buses and bus stops are also defined by coordinates. Since distance calculations are complex, I'm implementing this method in a backend with NodeJS. I've done some tests with the geoLib library.
However, the raw calculation and evaluation of distances is not exactly what I want, because this method must follow an additional logic: bus routes have a unique direction, so if I want to get the closest point of the bus it must take into account the direction of the journey.
For this reason I've been researching directed graphs. I already have a directed graph, the nodes being the waypoints of my route.
My main problem is how my program should choose the corresponding waypoints to calculate the distance to the stop.
PS: This is something like what I imagine: https://i.sstatic.net/653vUaFB.jpg

I have the impression there are several questions in your post. Can you break it down to one question and post the others as a separate question? If I understood you well, a (first) problem is how the connect the points to a directed graph. To answer that, it would help to know how exactly your data looks like (best would be a sample to share for testing). Are the points numbered in the order the bus will take? Then you could simply connect the points based on this order number.

Thank you very much for the quick reply @Babel! Of course, I will edit the post to ask only my main question. You asked for an example of my data. The routes are stored in my database like this:
  {
    "lat": 36.381923,
    "long": -6.172492
  },
  {
    "lat": 36.383927,
    "long": -6.19146
  },
  {
    "lat": 36.373285,
    "long": -6.177127
  }
]```
The points are sorted by themselves in the order the bus will take.
My main problem is which points should I choose to calculate the distance (in the attached image you can see it visually).

Please do not comment on your own post. If you have additional content, it should be added to the Question as an [Edit]. All graphics should be inserted through the SE editor, so it does not 404 over time. Thanks are discouraged here -- See the Help Center

Can you get your directed graph to calculate optimal paths? You simply determine the path from the current bus position, to the bus stop of interest, and then extract its length (distance).


Connect the points to a line in the order of the bus. Use Points to path tool.

Now measure the distance along the line from the point where the bus is right now to the desired station. Points (current bus postion; bus stops) might not lie exactly on the line, so you might have to snap the points to the line.


The expression used below calculates the distance of the yellow line - a distance along the bus route (black line) from the current position of the bus (red dot) to bus stop 3 (blue):

I show a way how the principle works - you can adapt it for the data/use case you have. Given the line bus_route, the point layers bus_stops and bus_current_position, from the last layer you can create the distance along the line to any of the stations - in the case here, stop 3. Function line_substring() snaps the points to the line.
The following expression calculates this distance (be aware of the CRS you use to get proper distances!):
    with_variable(
        'route',
        overlay_nearest ('bus_route', @geometry)[0],
    with_variable(
        'station',
        geometry (get_feature_by_id ('bus_stops', 3)),
    length(
        line_substring(
            @route,  -- line (route) of the bus
            line_locate_point (@route, @geometry),  -- postion of bus
            line_locate_point (@route, @station)  -- bus stop 3
        )
    )))

You could do all this by code in the Python console (as a start, see here). If you're not familiar, you might want to ask this on this site as a separate question. The policy of this site, however, is that you should do a code attempt when asking code related questios. A first step could be that you create a model and export it as Python code to get a start point.

Thank you so much @Babel! You are a life saver. Your answer sounds really good and is helpful to me. Do you think there is a way to do everything you have proposed through code alone? I have seen that QGIS has an API to be used with Python. Would this be a viable solution?

Okay, thanks! If I can't implement it I'll create a new question.
